# How can I display a random image on a web-page for 2 minutes, then change images?

Tags: php, html, image

I have a small php script that is supposed to display a random image from a folder then change images every 2 minutes.  The problem I'm running into is every so often, we get an error:

`NOT FOUND`

`ERROR:  could not connect to http://somedomain.com/TV/imgSlider.php`

Here is the script I'm using to pick a random image(out of a folder called `quotes`) to display, and refresh the page every 120 seconds(Using meta refresh):

```
<?php
    $dirContents = scandir('quotes');
    // Unset the ".." and "." that are included in the array returned by scandir()
    unset($dirContents[0]);
    unset($dirContents[1]);

?>
<html>
    <body bgcolor="black">
    <?php
        // Grab random index for the array then grab the image name and push it into
        // the <img> tag.
        $randImgIndex = array_rand($dirContents);
        $randImg = $dirContents[$randImgIndex];
        echo "<img src=\"quotes/$randImg\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%\">";
    ?>
    </body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">
</html>
```

Is there a reason why this script would throw that type of error(or why the script might not be accessible)? Anything I can do to prevent this error?  Any other methods of doing this that might help?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to refresh the page you can use the [meta-refresh directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

Comment: @clonerworks, I have just never used Jquery.  I don't need anything fancy, I just need to display a random image every 2 minutes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I'm using the meta refresh already.  The problem is that every once in a while, instead of just refreshing, it throws the error I mentioned in the op.

Comment: OK @DuckPuncher, your refresh method wasn't clear.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Yeah, I should be more clear on that.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in trying it with Jquery, personally i think it is a cleaner way then php for this process then try something like below:

```
 <script> 
  function changeImg(min, max) { // create the function for changing the images
        var noi = max - min; // number of images
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * noi) + min; // randomized number
        $("#banner").find("img").attr('src','pages/gallery/PhotoWall/images/' + ""+ numRand +"" + '.jpg'); // set a new image
    }

    $(function() { // Waiting for the DOM ready
        setInterval(function(){ // create an interval (loop)
        changeImg(101, 120); // the function with paramteters
        },1000); // the interval in millisecondes --> 1000 = 1 second
    });
</script>
```

Sourced from: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-a-random-picture-to-display

Comment: we might end up going this route.  My boss had something similar written in javascript and we ran into the same error.  I'm almost convinced it's the computers they are using to display the images...  Basically we have TVs set up around our building to display images, and they just put a browser into fullscreen mode, which is displayed on the TV, and they let the image slider run all day..

Comment: How many images are you using? I think a query slider would be the best option for you really if this is your situation this way the page doesnt need to refersh and shouldnt get the 404 errors as long as the images are on the same server as were the page is rendering from

Comment: Oh!  Perfect!  We will definitely be going this route then :P  Thanks!

Comment: this site may interest you also - http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html